# Android Volley with Restfull service

Tags: android, rest, android-volley, restful-architecture, restful-url

Hey can someone help me with this error. I made a connection between my android phone and laptop using restful service. The communication is established with success and I can receive from my service that json with all the information from the table "Autori", but when it comes to send an object from my phone the service doesn't know how to deserialize the json. Please judge my code base on the error given and not on the fact that is running on the main UI thread.
P.S. I mention that all the code on the server side had been generate buy Netbeans using "Entity class from database" and "REstfull Web service from Entity classes".

***Restfull service side***

Autori (is the bean class on the server side)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "autori")
@XmlRootElement

@NamedQueries({

    @NamedQuery(name = "Autori.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Autori a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Autori.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM Autori a WHERE a.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Autori.findByNume", query = "SELECT a FROM Autori a WHERE a.nume = :nume"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Autori.findByPrenume", query = "SELECT a FROM Autori a WHERE a.prenume = :prenume")})
public class Autori implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Nume")
    private String nume;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Prenume")
    private String prenume;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "iDAutori")
    private List<CarteAutori> carteAutoriList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private User idUser;

    public Autori() {
    }

    public Autori(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Autori(Integer id, String nume, String prenume) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nume = nume;
        this.prenume = prenume;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }

    public void setNume(String nume) {
        this.nume = nume;
    }

    public String getPrenume() {
        return prenume;
    }

    public void setPrenume(String prenume) {
        this.prenume = prenume;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<CarteAutori> getCarteAutoriList() {
        return carteAutoriList;
    }

    public void setCarteAutoriList(List<CarteAutori> carteAutoriList) {
        this.carteAutoriList = carteAutoriList;
    }

    public User getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(User idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Autori)) {
            return false;
        }
        Autori other = (Autori) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "qwe.Autori[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

User (another bean)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userName = :userName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByParola", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.parola = :parola"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByNume", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.nume = :nume"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPrenume", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.prenume = :prenume"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "parola")
    private String parola;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Nume")
    private String nume;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Prenume")
    private String prenume;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "iDUser")
    private List<UserRoluri> userRoluriList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idUser")
    private List<Autori> autoriList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "iDUser")
    private List<History> historyList;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(Integer id, String userName, String parola, String nume, String prenume, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.parola = parola;
        this.nume = nume;
        this.prenume = prenume;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getParola() {
        return parola;
    }

    public void setParola(String parola) {
        this.parola = parola;
    }

    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }

    public void setNume(String nume) {
        this.nume = nume;
    }

    public String getPrenume() {
        return prenume;
    }

    public void setPrenume(String prenume) {
        this.prenume = prenume;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<UserRoluri> getUserRoluriList() {
        return userRoluriList;
    }

    public void setUserRoluriList(List<UserRoluri> userRoluriList) {
        this.userRoluriList = userRoluriList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Autori> getAutoriList() {
        return autoriList;
    }

    public void setAutoriList(List<Autori> autoriList) {
        this.autoriList = autoriList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<History> getHistoryList() {
        return historyList;
    }

    public void setHistoryList(List<History> historyList) {
        this.historyList = historyList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "qwe.User[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

History (another bean)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "history")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "History.findAll", query = "SELECT h FROM History h"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "History.findById", query = "SELECT h FROM History h WHERE h.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "History.findByDataactiune", query = "SELECT h FROM History h WHERE h.dataactiune = :dataactiune"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "History.findByIdResursa", query = "SELECT h FROM History h WHERE h.idResursa = :idResursa"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "History.findByNumeactiune", query = "SELECT h FROM History h WHERE h.numeactiune = :numeactiune"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "History.findByStatus", query = "SELECT h FROM History h WHERE h.status = :status")})
public class History implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "DATAACTIUNE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataactiune;
    @Column(name = "id_resursa")
    private Integer idResursa;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "NUMEACTIUNE")
    private String numeactiune;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_User", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private User iDUser;

    public History() {
    }

    public History(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDataactiune() {
        return dataactiune;
    }

    public void setDataactiune(Date dataactiune) {
        this.dataactiune = dataactiune;
    }

    public Integer getIdResursa() {
        return idResursa;
    }

    public void setIdResursa(Integer idResursa) {
        this.idResursa = idResursa;
    }

    public String getNumeactiune() {
        return numeactiune;
    }

    public void setNumeactiune(String numeactiune) {
        this.numeactiune = numeactiune;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public User getIDUser() {
        return iDUser;
    }

    public void setIDUser(User iDUser) {
        this.iDUser = iDUser;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof History)) {
            return false;
        }
        History other = (History) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "qwe.History[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

AbstractFacade

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

Application Config

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(servicedfg.AutoriFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.CarteAutoriFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.CarteFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.DrepturiFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.EditorFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.HistoryFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.RoluriDrepturiFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.RoluriFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.UserFacadeREST.class);
        resources.add(servicedfg.UserRoluriFacadeREST.class);
    }

}
```

AutoriFacadeREST

```
@Stateless
@Path("qwe.autori")
public class AutoriFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Autori> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebApplication8PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public AutoriFacadeREST() {
        super(Autori.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void create(Autori entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Autori entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Autori find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }


    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Autori> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Autori> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

Output:
[Output of the running Restfull service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhUwR.jpg)

***Client side***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


        Gson gson=new Gson();
        Autori autori=new Autori();
        autori.setNume("Anonim1");
        autori.setPrenume("Anonim1");
        //The ID in the DataBase is AutoIncrementing for my Autori table


        User user=new User();
        user.setParola("anonim1");
        user.setPrenume("anonim1");
        user.setNume("anonim1");
        user.setEmail("anonim1");
        autori.setIdUser(user);
        //The ID in the DataBase is AutoIncrementing for my User table

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest= null;
        try {
            jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.5.150:8080/WebApplication8/webresources/qwe.autori", new JSONObject(gson.toJson(autori, Autori.class)),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                            if(null!=jsonObject)
                            {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Received form server a JSON that is not null");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.i(TAG,"Received form server a JSON that is NULL");
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Error: "+volleyError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Entire String: " + jsonObjectRequest.toString());
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

***Errors:***

*Server side*

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[servicedfg.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet servicedfg.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.isConstrainedObject(JAXBBeanValidator.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.shouldValidate(JAXBBeanValidator.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.validateAndBuildJAXBElement(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:660)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:852)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*Client side*

```
04-11 12:14:04.102 12065-12065/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-11 12:14:04.102 12065-12065/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:12065
04-11 12:14:04.182 12065-12065/project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.pos_tema_try1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.pos_tema_try1-2/lib/arm64
04-11 12:14:04.343 12065-12065/project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.pos_tema_try1 I/MainActivity: Entire String: [ ] http://192.168.5.150:8080/WebApplication8/webresources/qwe.autori 0x85f46c74 NORMAL null
04-11 12:14:04.433 12065-12106/project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.pos_tema_try1 I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 03b6da7, I49f5588d88
                                                                                      Build Date                       : 11/26/15
                                                                                      OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.02
                                                                                      Local Branch                     : 
                                                                                      Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF64.1.2.2_RB4.06.00.00.180.010
                                                                                      Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                                      Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
04-11 12:14:04.759 12065-12096/project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.pos_tema_try1 E/Volley: [89822] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://192.168.5.150:8080/WebApplication8/webresources/qwe.autori
04-11 12:14:04.773 12065-12065/project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.pos_tema_try1 E/MainActivity: Error: null
04-11 12:14:09.749 12065-12071/project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.pos_tema_try1 I/art: System.exit called, status: 1
```

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper seems to be the root cause. Are you sure, you included a library on the server containing this class?

Comment: No, I haven't. That class is automatically generated, I think in one of the steps using "Entity class from database" and "REstfull Web service from Entity classes".

Comment: Not working with the import of that library. [Importing org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper ][1]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz3c5.jpg

Comment: Any other ideas? Please .....